# Handle Multiple Conditions per Field - LWC Conditional Formatting

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm new here so hoping the title does well. I have something like this in my LWC -

```
//HTML
<template>
<lightning-input name="field1" type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
<lightning-input name="field2" type="text"></lightning-input>
<lightning-input name="field3" type="date"></lightning-input>
</template>
```

```
//js
var condition1 = true;
var condition2 = false;
```

The logic may be something like this:
**Field1** - IF condition1 = true AND condition2 = false
**Field2** - IF condition1 = true OR condition2 = false
**Field3** - IF condition1 = false AND condition2 = true

My best guess would be to have a single function that does something like

```
assignFieldVisibility() {
if (condition1 = true && condition2 = false) {
this.field1isVisible = true;
}
...//all the other fields
}
```

Then have a template wrap each field in the html pointing to the corresponding "isVisible" variable. 
I just wanted to check and see if this is the right way to do it. There are 20 or more fields that I need to apply this sort of thinking to with more than 2 conditions at times. It felt rather bulky to have a function with 20+ if statements and a template around each field. Any advice on a better way to manage this conundrum would be greatly appreciated.